# How to implement not-real time chat between clients in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, websocket, jms, chat

I would like to understand what's the best way to implement a very simple message exchange system between two clients, using Spring Boot as back-end and AngularJS as front-end.

I'm new to Spring, I'm studying it and using it for a University project.

Let's say that my project is a kind of a simplified e-commerce. I want to create a "conversation" between two clients (for example, something like the messaging system on eBay) based on the exchange of simple text messages. If one of the clients is not connected, he has to be able to retrieve the messages received while he was offline.

I came across several tutorials and guides but most of them explain how to create a real time "chat room" which is not what I'm looking for.

I would like to have some suggestions on what would be the best path to follow (JMS, WebSocket...) and why.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, treat messages as you would treat any other data. When someone sends a message, store it in the database. When someone reads its messags, get them from the database.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is going to elicit a lot of opinion-based feed-back. Do some more research and choose an architecture that suits your requirements. When you have concrete issues (not design ones) come back and ask. If you can't choose an architecture then implement a proof-of-concept with each choice and decide that way.

Comment: And by the way...As the developer of a message broker I think a database would be a poor choice for the back-end of an application like this.

Comment: @JustinBertram I've been resarching for so long without understanding which architecture would better fit my idea (probably because of my inexperience in this field), so opinions were actually what I was looking for. All the guides I read either led me to something different (for example, chat room) or to something that seemed too complex for what's my goal. I just wanted to have a general advice about the architecture I should use given my requirements.

Comment: Unfortunately Stack Overflow is not the place for general advice or opinion-based questions. As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), you should "avoid questions that are primarily opinion-based, or that are likely to generate discussion rather than answers." I recommend you choose an architecture and then ask specific questions about how to modify it for your specific needs. For example, a chat room solution, while more complex than you apparently need, would suffice for a conversation between just 2 users.